# Its possible to assign single name for more than one drop down list in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form with more than one drop down list.the code is below

```
 [select* Country id:CountryDropDown first_as_label "Select Your Country*" "Algeria" "Argentina" "Australia" "Austria" "Belgium" "Brazil" "Canada" "China" "France" "Germany" "India" "Italy" "New Zealand" "Poland" "South Africa" "South Korea" "Thailand" "United Arab Emirates" "United Kingdom" "USA" "Zimbabwe"] 


<label id="AlgeriaStates">[select State "Adrar" "Ain Defla" "Ain Temouchent" "Alger" "Annaba" "Batna" "Bechar" "Bejaia" "Biskra" "Blida" "Bordj Bou Arreridj" "Bouira" "Boumerdes" "Chlef" "Constantine" "Djelfa" "El Bayadh" "El Oued" "El Tarf" "Ghardaia" "Guelma" "Illizi" "Jijel" "Khenchela" "Laghouat" "Mascara" "Medea" "Mila" "Mostaganem" "Oran" "Ouargla" "Oum el Bouaghi" "Relizane" "Saida" "Setif" "Sidi Bel Abbes" "Skikda" "Souk Ahras" "Tamanghasset" "Tebessa" "Tiaret" "Tindouf" "Tipaza" "Tissemsilt" "Tizi Ouzou" "Tlemcen" "Wilaya de M'Sila" "Wilaya de Naama"]</label>


<label id="ArgentinaStates">[select State "Buenos Aires" "Catamarca" "Chaco" "Chubut" "Cordoba" "Corrientes" "Entre Rios" "Formosa" "Jujuy" "La Pampa" "La Rioja" "Mendoza" "Misiones" "Neuquen" "Rio Negro" "Salta" "San Juan" "San Luis" "Santa Cruz"]</label>

<label id="AustraliaStates"> [select State "Australian Capital Territory" "New South Wales" "Northern Territory" "Queensland" "South Australia" "Tasmania" "Victoria" "Western Australia"]</label>

[submit "SUBMIT"]
```

I have using JavaScript to show/hide depending up on the country fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("AlgeriaStates").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
  function displayTextField() {
    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").value;
    if (dropDownText == "Algeria") {
      document.getElementById("AlgeriaStates").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("AlgeriaStates").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("ArgentinaStates").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
  function displayTextField() {
    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").value;
    if (dropDownText == "Argentina") {
      document.getElementById("ArgentinaStates").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ArgentinaStates").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("AustraliaStates").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
  function displayTextField() {
    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").value;
    if (dropDownText == "Australia") {
      document.getElementById("AustraliaStates").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("AustraliaStates").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

I have using a single name field for all three state field as "State" for avoiding the empty field showing in the database. but its only taking the last field value. may the issue is because of duplication of the name field. if yes please provide a solution for resolving the same.

The working is fine. but while saving the data into database only taking last one field value.
that is, if selecting the country as Algeria or Argentina the database automatically taking the last field first value(ie,"Australian Capital Territory"). 
How to resolve the issue? please let me provide the solution .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function disableStateFields(){
    document.getElementById("AlgeriaStates").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("AlgeriaStates").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ArgentinaStates").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("ArgentinaStates").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("AustraliaStates").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("AustraliaStates").disabled = true;
  }

  function displayTextField() {
    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("CountryDropDown").value;
    disableStateFields()
    var id='';
    switch (dropDownText) {
      case "Algeria":
        id = "AlgeriaStates";
        break;
      case "Argentina":
        id= "ArgentinaStates";
        break;
      case "Australia":
        id= "AustraliaStates";
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
  }
  disableStateFields();
  document.getElementById( "CountryDropDown" ).addEventListener( "change", displayTextField);

</script>
```